# ¿Como soluciono este problema con mi menu?

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Los contextualizo para puntualizar lo que tengo en mente. Estoy programando un menú que consista en lo siguiente: Primero, preguntarle al usuario qué tipo de arreglo prefiere emplear (si uno generado aleatoriamente en un rango de 5 caracteres o uno introducido por el mismo usuario con el mismo rango de 5 caracteres). Para que después de haber seleccionado el tipo de arreglo, el usuario elija qué algoritmo de ordenamiento se ejecutará para ordenar el arreglo previamente establecido.
Sin embargo, no estoy muy seguro de como efectuar un menú de usuario de manera correcta, eficiente y eficaz; por lo que les agradecería mucho si me compartiesen sus sugerencias para ello o que me dijesen si hay algún error grave.
(El código para los algoritmos de ordenamiento los tengo en otro archivo de C, por lo que simplemente deberé referenciarlos y por ende no están en este código).

**El problema, es que al ejecutarlo obtengo un texto que dice:

> "[Warning] conflicting types for sortType".

¿Saben a qué se debe esto y de qué modo lo puedo solucionar?**

````
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, array[5];
    int i;
    int cont;
    int choice = 0;

    while (TRUE)
    {
    printf("1) numeros al azar\n");
            printf("2. numeros introducidos por el usuario\n");
            printf("\escriba el numero de la opcion que guste\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
    
            switch (choice)
            {
               case 1:
                  printf("Este es el arreglo generado aleatoriamente:\n\n");
                  srand(time(NULL));
                  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                  {
                    array[i]=1+rand()%999;
                    printf("Elemento: %d \n", (rand()));
                    
                  }
                  sortType();
               break;
            
               case 2:
                  printf("\nIntroduzca los numeros de su arreglo: \n");
                  sortType();
               break;
            }
         }
}

void sortType()
{
    int option = 0;
        
    while (TRUE)
    {
            printf("seleccione el algoritmo de ordenamiento: \n");
            printf("1) Bubble Sort.\n");
            printf("2) Merge Sort.\n");
            scanf("%d", &option);
    
            switch (option)
            {
               case 1:
                  printf("\nBubble Sort.\n");
                  break;
            
               case 2:
                  printf("\nMerge Sort.\n");
                  break;
           }
    
   }
}```
````

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir finalmente? Porque no me queda claro. Una cosa sí te puedo adelantar, y es el `while (TRUE)` que tienes en la función `sortType`. Una vez que entres ahí tu código no va a poder salir, ya que las sentencias `break` que tienes puestas afectar al `switch-case` al ser una sentencia de menor jerarquía. Repito, cuéntanos qué es lo que quieres obtener de una forma más concreta y podremos ayudar. Edita tu pregunta con esa nueva información que nos aportes.

Comment: "*Pero, no estoy seguro de como efectuar un menú de usuario de manera correcta y les agradecería mucho si me compartiesen sus sugerencias para ello*". Esta bien de la forma en la que lo estas haciendo, para lo que quieres hacer no hay mucho truco.

Comment: @Londo ¡Saludos! Y sí, muchas gracias por comentarme tu duda con respecto a mi duda justamente. Aquí lo expondré de manera muy resumida para únicamente editar mi pregunta con la nueva información, pero básicamente quiero hacer un menú para elegir primero el tipo de arreglo y después el tipo de ordenamiento.

Comment: Pero cual es el problema?

Comment: @gbianchi Muchas gracias por comentarme eso y sí, me faltó incluir el error o problema. Ya lo he añadido y de nuevo, muchas gracias por comentármelo.

Comment: Te respondo más en profundidad en las respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Vayamos por partes...

1. Las instrucciones booleanas como `true` o `false` **NUNCA VAN EN MAYÚSCULAS**. Si quieres tener un bucle infinito deberás hacerlo del modo `while (true) {...}`. Además deberás incluir la librería `stdbool.h`.
2. En la línea `printf("\escriba el numero de la opcion que guste\n");` ten cuidado, porque te está cogiendo el `\e` como un elemento especial como puede ser el salto de línea `\n` o retorno de carro `\r`. Elimina la barra `\` o simplemente añade un espacio entre la barra y el comienzo de tu frase.
3. En el primer `switch-case` llamas en ambas opciones a la función `sortType()`. Si esto es correcto indica que la vas a ejecutar siempre, y por lo tanto tendría más sentido sacarla fuera de las opciones y ejecutarla siempre después de elegir las opciones. De cualquier modo lo dejo como lo tienes, ya que eres tú el que tiene el código y quizá tenga sentido hacerlo así.
4. El error que comentas de *[Warning] conflicting types for sortType* no lo veo por ningún lado al compilar el código con los apaños que he realizado. Aunque todo tiene pinta de que estás llamando a una función que todavía no ha sido leída. Este tipo de warnings desaparece si implementas la función `sortType()` antes del `main`.
5. Te recomiendo evitar usar bucles infinitos, ya que si no estás familiarizado con el lenguaje puede que te quedes atrapado dentro. Emplea mejor variables de control que manejas dentro del programa, y que cuando ésta variable tenga un valor en particular te permita salir del `while`.

Quizá sí estaría bien "maquillar" un poco la apariencia de tu programa para hacerlo más legible de cara al usuario, es decir, modificar el GUI que aparece.

Una posibilidad sería dejarlo de esta manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void sortType()
{
    int option = 10; // Inicializamos con cualquier valor distinto de 0
        
    while (option!=0)
    {
        printf("\n-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Seleccione el algoritmo de ordenamiento: \n");
        printf("1. Bubble Sort.\n");
        printf("2. Merge Sort.\n");
        printf("0. SALIR.\n");
        printf("\nOPCION: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
    
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nBubble Sort.\n");
                // Incluir código de bubble
                break;
            
            case 2:
                printf("\nMerge Sort.\n");
                // Incluir código de merge
                break;
                
            case 0:
                printf("Saliendo de sortType...\n");
                break;
                
            default:    // RECOMENDABLE SIEMPRE PONER EL DEFAULT
                printf("Opcion incorrecta\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n, array[5];
    int i;
    int cont;
    int choice = 10;    // Inicializamos con cualquier valor distinto de 0

    while (choice!=0)
    {
        printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf(" ----------- ELIJA UNA OPCION -----------\n");
        printf("1. numeros al azar\n");
        printf("2. numeros introducidos por el usuario\n");
        printf("0. SALIR.\n");
        printf("\nOPCION: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n-----------------------------------------\n");
                printf("Este es el arreglo generado aleatoriamente:\n");
                srand(time(NULL));
                for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    array[i]=1+rand()%999;
                    printf("Elemento: %d \n", array[i]);
                }
                sortType();
                break;
            
            case 2:
                printf("\n-----------------------------------------\n");
                printf("\nIntroduzca los numeros de su arreglo: \n");
                for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    printf("Elemento %d: ", i+1);
                    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
                }
                sortType();
                break;
                
            case 0:
                printf("Saliendo de main...\n");
                break;
                
            default:    // RECOMENDABLE SIEMPRE PONER EL DEFAULT
                printf("Opcion incorrecta\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    
    printf(" -- FIN DE PROGRAMA --");
}
```

Ahora ya corre de tu cuenta incluir las funciones que dices poseer en otro script para que te funcione correctamente. No dudes en volver si tienes más dudas.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Londo por las sugerencias, las consideré e incluí las funciones pertenecientes a otros scripts por lo que todo finalmente funciona a la perfección. (:

Comment: Me alegro! No olvides dejar una puntuación positiva si te sirvió! Si tienes más dudas aquí estamos y sigue dándole duro ;)